# set keyboard shortcut to open text button inside screenshot markup

Tags: keyboard, applescript, screen-capture, markup

trying to enable it so that when i press t inside a screenshot markup, the text button is clicked

[image]

here's my working script:

```
tell application "System Events" to click button 2 of window "Screen Shot" of process "screencaptureui"
```

just need to activate the shortcut at the right time, and deactivate it while typing inside the textbox obviously..

Comment: For something like, this there is not really a need to write it in that manner when simply `tell application "System Events" to click button 2 of window 1 of process "screencaptureui"` does the job.

Comment: yeah but are you able to do this?

Comment: What you are asking to do is not doable with basic _vanilla_ **AppleScript**